# Is there a relationship with how many lines are necessary to divide a circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, divisibility

I want to use the example of a circle being divided increasing by 1 each time ( 1/1 , 1/2 , 1/3 , 1/4 , etc.). In order it would take this amount of lines: 0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, and so on. Is it that an odd division would require an inverse amount of lines (i.e. dividing by 9 correlates to 9 lines) while even division would require half of it’s inverse (i.e. dividing by 16 would require 8 lines)? And if that is the case is there any equation to express this relationship? Would the series diverge or converge?

Comment: In more advanced mathematics we usually reserve the word "circle" for the *curve* and use the word "disk" for *the union of the circle and everything inside it*; here I think you're referring to the disk.  In any case, you are asking a very interesting question. But the question would be improved if you could be specific about exactly what kinds of "division" you are allowing.

Comment: Good point. I’m referring to a division that splits the area of the (circle?) disk into equal parts. The division would follow that the denominator starts from 1 and increases by 1 with every iteration (with the numerator remaining as 1 the entire time).

Comment: Do you perhaps mean line segments instead of lines? Otherwise, you can't divide into exactly 3 parts with 3 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you need to find the number of line segments required to divide a circle into $n$ **sectors** of equal area. In that case each sector has a central angle $\frac{2\pi}n$. Let $D(n)$ denote the number of line segments you need to perform the required division.

You can think of it this way: draw the radii for the first sector inclined to each other at the angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ calling them $r_1$ and $r_2$, then draw the next radius $r_3$ inclined to $r_2$ at the same angle, and continue on until you have drawn the $n$th radius. It’s clear from here that we have drawn $n$ radii, so if none of them form a straight line segment then $D(n)=n$.

Denote by $k = \frac{n}2$. Clearly if $k \in \mathbb Z$, then $r_m$ and $r_{m+k}$ for $m \le k$ would form a straight line segment since $k\frac{2\pi}n = \pi$. That would mean exactly $k$ line segments would be required for the division since $k$ radii get added up with the remaining $k$ radii in pairs to form line segments.

So we conclude that $$D(n) = \begin{cases}
n : \text{odd n} \\
\frac{n}2 : \text{even n}
\end{cases}$$